# Ionic 3 using ion-checkbox for only select one

Tags: ionic-framework, checkbox, ionic3

How can I using checkbox for select one (just like radio), my code:

```
<div *ngFor="let address of addresses; let i = index;">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-checkbox id="cb_{{address.id}}" (ionChange)="selectedAddress(address.id,addresses,i)" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

in ts file:

```
selectedAddress(id,addresses,index){
  for(let i=0; i<addresses.length; i++){
    if(index != i){
      document.getElementById("cb_"+addresses[i].id).checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

but it is not working, anyone know how to achieve it? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind address.checked = false; kind thing when page is loading using for loop or using the API.

pass address object trough 
             selectedAddress(address,addresses,i) method.

in.ts
            selectedAddress(address,addresses,i)
            {
             address.checked = !address.checked;
            }